# Indenting wrapped text of a bullet in HTML vs Outlook Email

Tags: html, css, outlook

Would anyone know how to get around this problem I'm having where, in a series of bullets, indenting the wrapped text in a browser works fine, but when the table code is used in an Outlook email, the padding-left and text-indent css properties have no effect?

```
padding-left: 1em;text-indent: -1em;
```

When looking around for help, I found this page which seems to indicate Outlook supports the text-indent property, but not the padding property (if I'm looking at it right): https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Neither CSS property has any affect at all on the wrapped text alignment in an email though.  The current version of Outlook being used by anyone that looks at this page will be Outlook 2013 or greater.

Would anyone know of a work around for this?   Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work and makes the HTML version look bad actually.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the rest of your code, so I can't test what you're doing. The approach outlined below works for me.

I see you have tried `padding-left: 1em;text-indent: -1em;`

Try dropping the padding and set the style specifically for Outlook:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
  li {text-indent: -1em;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This should correct Outlook and leave modern email clients alone.

If this doesn't work, post your code so we can get a closer look at what might be the issue.

Good luck.